# Unity: Ignore collision of a plateform if jump to it from below. Using ContactFilter & rigidBody.Cast()

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am able to avoid a collision between my player and my entire plateform with the use of contactFilter2D.SetLayerMask() + rigidBody2D.Cast(Vector2, contactFilter, ...);

But I don't find a way to avoid the collision only if my player try to acces to the plateform from below it (with a vertical jump).
I'm pretty sure I should use the contactFilter2D.setNormalAngle() (after specify the minAngle and maxAngle) but no matter the size of my angles, I can't pass threw it.

This is how I initialize my contactFilter2D.

```
protected ContactFilter2D cf;

void Start () {
    cf.useTriggers = false;
    cf.minNormalAngle = 0;
    cf.maxNormalAngle = 180;
    cf.SetNormalAngle(cf.minNormalAngle, cf.maxNormalAngle);
    cf.useNormalAngle = true;      
}

void Update () {

}
```

I use it with

```
count = rb.Cast(move, contactFilter, hitBuffer, distance + shellRadius);
```

Any ideas ? If you want more code, tell me. But I don't think it will be usefull to understand the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unity actualy has a ready made component for this: it is a physics component called "Platform Effector 2D" if you drag and drop it on your platform it will immediately work the way you want, and it has adjustable settings for tweaking the parameters. hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ! I did not kow this component and it works perfectly.
I just wonder how am I able to reproduice this component by script (if I want to manage it in some way later)

Comment: After some use with the Platform Effector 2D, I am able to avoid the collision from the top of the platform. But impossible to do it just for the bottom.
(I tried with rotational offset at 0 and 180, with or without use collider mask)

Comment: Solved by scripting the exception if the collider object has an PlatformEffector2D at my own physics.
But I've got some issues to the non-horizontal platform, as a / (<- this is the shape of my platform because I don't find the word to discribe it :x).
The player is not set as grounded and start falling threw the platform after a few seconds